# SQL Cant Include Column Table after SUM column table in SELECT SYNTAX

Tags: sql, oracle

I have SQL syntax like this :

```
SELECT FORM_NO, SUM(QTY) as QTY FROM SEIAPPS_QTY WHERE FORM_NO = '1' AND STATUS_QTY='OK'
```

But facing problem with error like this :

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

I saw error from FORM_NO, how can I include that FORM_NO ?

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle you need to use GROUP BY on the values you wish to retrieve (that are not in a group function):

```
SELECT FORM_NO, SUM(QTY) as QTY FROM SEIAPPS_QTY WHERE FORM_NO = '1' AND STATUS_QTY='OK' GROUP BY FORM_NO
```

Comment: Not only Oracle requires this. Any ANSI SQL compliant DBMS does.

Answer (score 1):

You need a group by

```
SELECT FORM_NO, SUM(QTY) as QTY 
FROM SEIAPPS_QTY 
WHERE FORM_NO = '1' 
  AND STATUS_QTY='OK'
GROUP BY FORM_NO
```

-Or-

Since you're selecting a single form you can drop the form number

```
SELECT SUM(QTY) as QTY 
FROM SEIAPPS_QTY 
WHERE FORM_NO = '1' 
  AND STATUS_QTY='OK'
```

-Or-

If you really want the single FORM_NO in the result, use an arbitrary aggregate function

```
SELECT MIN(FORM_NO) AS FORM_NO, SUM(QTY) as QTY 
FROM SEIAPPS_QTY 
WHERE FORM_NO = '1' 
  AND STATUS_QTY='OK'
GROUP BY FORM_NO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FORM_NO, SUM(QTY) as QTY FROM SEIAPPS_QTY WHERE FORM_NO = '1' AND STATUS_QTY='OK'
GROUP BY FORM_NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
SELECT FORM_NO, SUM(QTY) QTY
FROM   SEIAPPS_QTY 
WHERE  FORM_NO = '1' 
AND STATUS_QTY='OK'
GROUP BY form_no;
```

Or you can try this to get the the sum of `qty` for `form_no = 1`

```
SELECT SUM(qty) QTY
FROM   SEIAPPS_QTY 
WHERE  FORM_NO = '1' 
AND STATUS_QTY='OK';
```